ISCSI initiator: the GUID passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data provider
Windows Server 2019  Hyper V host.
Software MSiSCSI initiator connects to ISCSI target for backups.
Worked fine for years.
Backup failures started a few weeks ago with ISCSI errors.
I removed the existing connection and tried to setup a new one.
Adding a new destination results in the error:

The GUID passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data provider

System event Log shows event ID 113 with error:

iSCSI discovery via SendTargets failed with error code 0x00001068 to
target portal *<ip_address> 0003260 ROOT\ISCSIPRT\0000_0

I have:

Replaced the target device (QNAP NAS)
Reconfigured the target without CHAP
Created a new target
Rebooted the initiator machine

The issue seems not the target or the network, because I can connect successfully from other machines.
Initiator machine has latest updates and no issues showing up in DSIM or SFC.
Backups are working again using a file share, but I would prefer ISCSI because it's faster.
To reinstall ISCSI initiator I could remove and reinstall the "File and Storage Services Role", but this would also remove the Storage Pool configured on the server, and I'm not eager to fiddle with it.

I was able to fix it this way:

From Device Manager, remove "Microsoft iSCSI Initiator" under Storage Controller
From menù "Action / Add legacy hardware", choose "Manual install", "Stroage controllers" and add "Microsoft iSCSI Initiator" again

